# Derived property/field on derived classes: 'inheritance ladder' on both container class and one of its fields

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to apologize in advance if this is already answered. Since I did not know how to properly word it in the title, I may have missed another similar question. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346745/inheritance-derived-properties-in-derived-class), which is similar but I don't think it is exactly the same, since it does not aim for a hierarchical structure like what I'll describe.

Say I have a base class and base field, and a method `DoStuff()` that acts on said field

```
class MyContainer
{
    MyField field = new MyField();
    
    protected virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        field.foo1 = "a";
        field.foo2 = "b";
    }
}
```

Now, I want to extend MyContainer, and I create MyContainerExt, which should also contain a derived version of MyField (MyFieldExt). MyContainerExt would override DoStuff() to do some extra stuff on MyFieldExt, but I also want the DoStuff() from my base class to be done: essentially, I want to do the 'base' stuff and initializations from the base MyContainer class, and add on top extra initializations that potentially require the new fields/properties added on the derived MyFieldExt.

To add on top of that, say now I want to have MyContainerExtExt, which has a field derived from MyFieldExt (i.e. MyFieldExtExt), which I want to do stuff on on top of what the parent classes were already doing.

To be honest, I have no idea how to tackle this in an organized and non-smelly way. To give you an idea, this would be what I would love to have (if you could override properties with derived types, which I know you cannot):

```
class MyContainer
{
    abstract MyField Foo {get; set; }
    
    protected virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        Foo.foo1 = "a";
        Foo.foo2 = "b";
    }
}


class MyContainerExt: MyContainer
{
    override MyFieldExt Foo {get; set;}  // I know, this is not legal

    protected override void DoStuff()
    {
        base.DoStuff();  // The DoStuff() from the base class is applied
        Foo.foo3 = "c";  // Potentially, foo3 and foo4 are fields added to MyFieldExt that
        Foo.foo4 = "d";  //    the base class MyField knows nothing about
    }
}


class MyContainerExtExt: MyContainerExt
{
    override MyFieldExtExt Foo {get; set;}  // I know, this is not legal (again)

    protected override void DoStuff()
    {
        base.DoStuff();  // The DoStuff() from the first derived class (MyContainerExt( is applied
        Foo.foo5 = "e";  // Again, foo5 and foo6 are fields added to MyFieldExtExt that
        Foo.foo6 = "f";  //    the base class MyFieldExt knows nothing about
    }
}
```

This may not make sense at first, but I would like to have a hierarchical structure where maybe I have multiple variations on each 'inheritance level':

```
> MyContainer
>> MyContainerExt1, MyContainerExt2...
>>> MyContainerExt1Ext1, MyContainerExt1Ext2, MyContainerExt2Ext1, MyContainerExt2Ext2...
```

and I want to take the common factor that these classes have to do on one of their fields: most (if not everything) that MyContainer needs to do on its MyField-type field, will need to be done by all of its childs, with the caveat that the childs of MyContainer also have derived versions of MyField. I would also like this to be relatively easy to expand: I would not like a solution that 'manages' to make this ladder work for up to 3 levels of inheritance like in the example. I may not need more, but I would like the code I am making to be expandable in the future in case of a MyContainerExtExtExt...Ext or whatever the case may be.

I am not fixed on the structure at all: it can be property-based, or private fields that the child classes have to re-implement, or whatever. I just want a relatively clean way to achieve initializing/working on the derived versions of MyField without copying all the lines from the parent's DoStuff() into the children's DoStuff() methods (which defeats the point of inheritance).

In case anyone is wondering, I need this for structuring my Models and ViewModels in a heavily hierarchical WPF application (ViewModel == MyContainer, Model == MyField), but this should not affect the question I think.

I am using .NET 4.5.2, by the way, so any new tricks are welcome up to that point.

**EDIT:**
I ended up with something very similar to InBetween's answer below. It is sort of what I was going for before asking, but it did not seem to sit right so I wanted to double check there was no standard/better way of doing it. My final structure is something the likes of:

```
class MyContainer
{
    protected MyField Foo {get; set; }

    public MyContainer()
    {
        Foo = new MyField();
    }
    
    protected virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        Foo.foo1 = "a";
        Foo.foo2 = "b";
    }
}


class MyContainerExt: MyContainer
{
    public MyContainerExt()
    {
        Foo = new FieldExt();  // no need to override anything for this to work
    }

    protected override void DoStuff()
    {
        base.DoStuff();  // The DoStuff() from the base class is applied
        
        MyFieldExt foo = (MyFieldExt)Foo;  // The cast always works, since Foo is initialized as FieldExt
        foo.foo3 = "c";  // Potentially, foo3 and foo4 are fields added to MyFieldExt that
        foo.foo4 = "d";  //    the base class MyField knows nothing about
    }
}


class MyContainerExtExt: MyContainerExt
{
    public MyContainerExtExt()
    {
        Foo = new FieldExtExt();  // no need to override anything for this to work
    }

    protected override void DoStuff()
    {
        base.DoStuff();  

        MyFieldExtExt foo = (MyFieldExtExt)Foo;  // The cast always works, since Foo is initialized as FieldExtExt
        Foo.foo5 = "e";  // Again, foo5 and foo6 are fields added to MyFieldExtExt that
        Foo.foo6 = "f";  //    the base class MyFieldExt knows nothing about
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with `public abstract class MyContainer<T> where T: MyField
    {
        public abstract T Foo { get; set; }` That may, or may not, help.

Comment: [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). I don't think inheritance is suitable here.

Comment: Hey Sweeper, how would you tackle this neatly using composition? I thought inheritance sounded like the most organized way to go at it, considering I am looking at a tree structure of classes where every class in a 'level' has to implement everything from previous levels and expand on it...

And mjwills, truth is I am not very familiar with generics... I saw something like that, but got the feel it could not be expanded 'down the ladder of inheritance' easily... can it?

Comment: @Arce11 Did my suggestion help at all?

Comment: @mjwills As I said I am not very familiar with generics. Right now I am close to finishing structuring my code (not the toy example) to try and work with casting, since it was already more or less the way I was going for. If that fails, I will look into using generics on my base class. If you could provide an example though, it would certainly help a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. Given your base type;

```
class MyContainer
{
    abstract MyField Foo {get; set; }

    protected virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        Foo.foo1 = "a";
        Foo.foo2 = "b";
    }
}
```

There is no need to redeclare `MyField` in derived types, just cast it to the more specific type:

```
class MyContainerExt: MyContainer
{

    protected override void DoStuff()
    {
        base.DoStuff();
        var specificFoo = Foo as MyFieldExt; //this cast will always succeed
        specificFoo.foo3 = "c";  
        specificFoo.foo4 = "d";
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose I would need to do the casting every time I want to work on the MyFieldExt-specific fields, right? This would not be a problem, since I don't deal with them that often in my case. However, are the MyFieldExt-specific fields saved on the Foo property (of type MyField) after the DoStuff() method is over?

Comment: @Arce11: Yes, they will stay in memory.